# capture images from usb camera in windows 7 using c#

Tags: c#, windows-7, camera

Well i noticed that Microsoft seams to try to drop WIA 
There are tricks around it (downloading dll's register them etc)
But i wonder if i like to grab pictures fast over USB
What would the 'official' Microsoft way now be these days ?
I'm using windows 7 and visual studio express 2010

Perhaps you can hint me some code suggestion if possible, or articles about it.

Comment: i wonder why this question got a lowered score ? isnt it ok to ask a question anymore

Answer (score 1):

i stopped looking for it, i am using Aforge now and it works great.

its a bit sad it got down voted without a comment or suggestion, to help me find it.
i am sure Microsoft would prefer something to talk to its own video cams, but it stays unknown i am afraid, on the other hand Aforge is fast and works good.